# Можно ли связать таблицы связью "один ко многим", не используя внешний ключ?

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Можно ли связать таблицы связью "один ко многим", не используя **внешний ключ**?
Предположим, у меня есть таблица **products** с первичным ключом **id**. И вторая таблица с информацией о количестве произведенной продукции в год **productions** и составным первичным ключом (**product_id** & **year**).

Ниже наглядный пример того, что я имею ввиду:

```
products  |   productions 
------------------------
0         |    0  2020
1         |    0  2021
          |    1  2020
```

Если связать **id** таблицы **products** с **product_id** таблицы **productions** это будет связь один к одному или один ко многим? Я знаю, что связь между двумя первичными ключами это один к одному. Но в данном примере к продукту с id = 0 относится 2 записи из таблицы productions, а это уже один ко многим...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Я знаю, что связь между двумя первичными ключами это один к одному.

У вас со стороны `productions` используется не первичный ключ, а его часть, так что данное правило тут не применимо.

> Если связать id таблицы products с product_id таблицы productions это будет связь один к одному или один ко многим?

`product_id` обычное не уникальное поле, так что будет классическая связь один-ко-многим.